# Wireless network

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have a wireless router connected to a modem. I'd to add a wireless router in another area of the house to use to connect other devices. Is this possible to add wireless router without connecting via cable to the 1 router coming off of the modem?

Answer (score 1):

Search for "wireless repeater" or "wireless extender"

> Unlike adding a traditional access point to your network to expand
>   wireless coverage, wireless range extenders do not need to be
>   connected to the network by a data cable. Just put the wireless range
>   extender within range of your main access point or wireless router,
>   and it "bounces" the signals out to remote wireless devices.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can buy an access point and configure it in repeater mode. This is fairly simple just google how to configure [your access point model] in repeater mode. You can also use a wireless router (usually cheaper than an access point) to do the same. Please check this [link](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/diy-it-guy/diy-setting-up-wireless-access-points-as-repeaters-to-extend-wireless-range/).

I usually face a lot of problems with wireless repeaters as the connection is not that reliable specially is the distance between the routers/access points is big. It is alway better to connect the two routers/access points through an ethernet cable if at all possible.